# ezPublish - How to let users add content objects

Tags: ezpublish

I have already asked this question on share.ez.no. But since I didn't get any question or answer back, I thought let me try my favorite site and see if it gets some traction.

I want to accomplish following:

I want to provide a link or button on simple article page.
When user clicks that, it should take him to a form that lets him add a particular content object. This object is of a custom class (imaginary!) that I have already created.

TestClass - FullName, EmailAddress.

Later on, I would like to use these objects to display the list and also particular object on a single details page.

My Questions based on lot of time I spent on documentation:

1) What is it that I am looking for? Is it "Edit" or "Create"? Is "edit" also used for "create"??

2) What kind of template should I use for "Create"? System or Node template?

At one point it looked like Node. But basic node templates did not have anything for "create". There was a system template for "create".

3) How do I create a link or button for letting the user click it and reach a web form to create the object / submit his entry? I was hoping the article editor should have this facility.

(I do not want to use the ez toolbar.)

4) I looked at Edit templates. Specially the one that is used by comment page from an article page. But I couldn't understand it. As the template uses object id. In case of adding a new object, there wouldn't be any object id. Is it? How does edit template works then?

5) I also did not find a sinlge article that shows how to create such functionality which should be very common. I found one article on how to create forms, but that uses information collector functionality which is not what I am looking for. As it will let me see the results from setup section. I rather want to manage this information completely in the front-end.

I hope someone can point me to a step-by-step article. Or clarify some of these questions. Eventually I am poised to write such article due to all the pain I have gone through happy.gif Emoticon

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you don't want to use the toolbar (which would make this a ten minute job to setup), but really it looks like you should at least look at the code in there.  And remember, the toolbar is just another (override-able) template you can embed anywhere on your page and restyle via CSS.  As I assume your experience level with eZ is not huge, the easy way for you might be to use the toolbar but override its template to the extent that it only has one button on it. Then set-up the security policies so that the button becomes available under the correct conditions.  Should take maybe an hour or less to get working right as just one button.

Comment: Hi vlc, That's a great answer. Thank you. I have already been able to achieve the said functionality by doing pretty much the same steps. Looking at how toolbar does it, and security policies for the button to be available.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer i posted on the eZ Publish Community website, sharing it with all of you here : 
http://share.ez.no/forums/general/how-to-let-users-add-content-objects/comment66112

Cheers

Comment: Nicolas, thanks for the answer on ezcommunity. But, I'm just leaving a note here, that I couldn't get answers to my questions. This way others can still attempt to answer.